# How do I add style names to grid rows without selecting them?

Tags: css, vaadin, highlight, vaadin8

I want to style a grid row after clicking on it. I get the grid row / item in the `itemClickListener`, but I need to avoid using `grid.select(item)`. I have achieved the desired output which would highlight the row I clicked on with the grid select method, but this causes problems for my app since I do not want that row to be *selected*, but I want it to be just highlighted, e.g. apply a CSS style to said row. This is my code so far:

```
grid.addItemClickListener(e -> {
  grid.deselectAll();
  grid.select(e.getItem());
});
```

as well as:

```
grid.setStyleGenerator(row -> grid.getSelectedItems().contains(row)
    ? getRowSelectedStyle(row)
    : null);
```

I cannot seem to find anything on the forums which could apply a style name for the *clicked* row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to add a property to your item Bean, se "clicked".

Then you could do

```
grid.addItemClickListener(e -> {
    e.getItem().setClicked(true);
    grid.getDataProvider().refreshItem(e.getItem());
});
```

And

```
grid.setStyleGenerator(row -> row.isClicked()
    ? getRowSelectedStyle(row)
    : null);
```

Comment: I had the exact same thing in mind, but did not know that I needed to refresh the item. In addition I added some code to deselect all items upon selecting a new one:

`e.getSource().getDataProvider().fetch(new HierarchicalQuery<>(null, null)).forEach(item ->{item.setClicked(false);facetSearchPanel.getSearchResultPanel().getResultTable().getDataProvider().refreshItem(item);});`